# What is Unpack's "binary string"

Tags: php, unpack

I'm trying to the `unpack` function. The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) says

> Unpacks from a binary string into an
>   array according to the given format.

Does the string passed have to be a binary string? and what exactly is a binary string?

Comment: I wonder why are you trying to use unpack, maybe some other function will be easier to reach your final goal? If it is only for trying it ignore this comment. Otherwise I'd be glad to hear what are you trying to do with it. And then maybe we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: Is this a general question for your own knowledge, or are you trying to use this function for something?

Answer (score 1):

A `binary string` just means data that is in it's base binary format. The data it's self is being displayed as a string to you if you where to echo it, but it would be meaningless without applying it's correct structure to it. So for example a number would not look like a number, because it's in binary. While the data is there, it has to be parsed as a number for it to be readable as a number otherwise it could look like 'abcd'.

Answer (score 0):

if you read down slightly further you will see examples of what binary strings look like

`$binarydata = "\x32\x42\x00\xa0";`

Also the description of the method clearly says `Unpacks from a binary string`, so yes it requires a binary string.

more information on [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary#Computing)